Can a Merchant Really Charge to My Credit Card with Only the Number, Name and Expiry Date?
I was talking to a hotel and to reserve a room, they asked for my credit card details.
It was not a payment via a secure link like online shopping (where I even get an app notification to authorise a specific amount which is shown in the notification that I authorise).
But the hotel asked the following details on an email

Card Number (it's a master card)
My name
Expiry date

Surprisingly, they did not ask for CVC, and I did not give it either. But nonetheless, after about a week, I got a message from my bank that my account has been charged with the amount (in a foreign currency, where the hotel is located).
This transaction in itself is legit, but it got me thinking, is it that easy to charge a card without even knowing the CVC and an app notification for me to authorise it?
How does it work behind the scene? Does it mean my bank will give the money to anyone who comes to it with the credit card number? Or, did the hotel operator forward my credit card details to its own bank, which came to my bank get the money? How does either bank verify the amount, or whether subsequent transactions are authorised from the same card? Is it purely a matter of trusting that merchant?
If the details matter, my bank is

DBS (a Singapore bank)
the merchant is Hilton Hong Kong

But I suppose the rules should be agnostic to these details?

Note that sending your credit card details over plaintext email is risk of fraud, and requesting that you provide those details by email is against the hotel's terms and conditions as a payment processor. Every single credit card that is recorded on their email server represents a potential $20,000 USD fine that MC can impose on them for breaking their agreement. Such information can be provided over the phone or via encrypted online channels, but sending over email is forbidden.

I had assumed that "I was talking to a hotel" meant "over the phone", which sidesteps the security concerns around email/plaintext.

@MooingDuck: Right, but the wording "But the hotel asked the following details on an email" is concerning! It's not clear whether they asked in an email (and wanted the details on the phone), or they asked on the phone for the details to be sent in an email. the former is probably OK; the latter is not.

Note too that it's quite likely it was not actually a charge, but, just a hold or check on the card.  That happens a lot with hotel bookings.

Yes, that's how it was for decades. CVC is a relatively new addition, and pre-approval is not necessary.
Generally, a transaction that was not pre-approved, was not made in person, and the merchant doesn't have any details other than those printed on the front of the card (like what you're describing) would be immediately reversed if the cardholder disputed. But if the transaction is legit as you say, then there's no problem.

A merchant who requests CVC s at less risk of fraud, and may be able to get a better processing charge from the credit card network. On the other hand. it means they may be putting the customer at a bit more risk if the card information is stolen on their end (though they aren't supposed to store the CVC). Trade-offs. Historically hotels have just taken the card number and name over the phone, so there may be customer resistance to adding CVC.

@keshlam The hotel, at most, is going to charge one night to the card in event of a cancellation. There's not really fraud where people make reservations with stolen cards and don't show up. When the cardholder actually checks in, they will run the card again as a card-present transaction, which has the lowest risk and best rates.

I'm not sure about this but I think whether a CVC is required depends on the merchant's relationship and/or status with the credit card vendor. I've had companies successfully bill me without my card's current expiration date. A CC company's profits depend heavily on limiting costs associated with fraud.

I think all the comments are correct. CVC may be required as a defense from chargeback (without it a non-present transaction dispute will be accepted by the processor by default); expiration may not be necessary for recurring transactions (after the first one), but usually is required for a one-off or a first in a series; and hotels do routinely take credit cards over the phone for securing the reservation, but run them again as card-present transaction for the actual bill.

My cards either have the numbers printed at the back or not printed on the card at all.

@gerrit that's also a new thing. Many cards still have them on the front, some still embossed, even, for "ironing".

@littleadv what's this "ironing" thing you speak of?

@justhalf A credit card imprinter, used to record the numbers onto paper sheets using carbon copy transfer. before electronic transmission became ubiquitous, or when early electronic systems went down.

Payment processors have a LOT of flexibility as to what it can be charged with. The issue isn't whether it can be charged, but who loses money when it is contested.
There are multiple levels of security the vendor can choose, from the extremely risky "Charge only on number, ignore any warnings", to "Everything must absolutely match, and reject on any errors". Neither extremes are viable options.
What happens is different levels of security gives different levels of protection and liability. If the vendor decides to charge a card based on number alone, with no check on name/expiry validity, then vendor eats the cost and the CC isn't even going to bat an eye when they refuse the charge. It's pretty stupid to do this and nobody really does this, but you CAN do it.
Of course, if a merchant has rampant amounts of fraudulent charges, then they're going to land in hot water very fast.

Some providers even allow requring different levels of verfication based on various risk factors.

What you described (minus the whole sending your card details over email ) is literally exactly the same details that the world's largest online retailer - Amazon - use to charge debit & credit cards (in the UK, maybe elsewhere too).
They do not ask for or need your CVV/CVC security code to charge you:

It is up to the merchant to choose which anti-fraud checks they do. One such check is CVV code. Another common check is that the address you gave matches the one held on file at your bank or financial institution - but again this is optional, and it is up to the merchant; since they are the ones who would incur a chargeback fee from their payment processor, have a high fraud rate with them, etc.
The "rules" that you are talking about, that apply to merchants, are typically PCI DSS. You mentioned that your card is a Mastercard. Mastercard require compliance with PCI DSS; as do Visa, American Express, Discover, and JCB, plus others. A PCI DSS compliant merchant should never ask you to send your card details over email. I am 99% sure that this is a breach of these regulations. After a quick skim of the requirements, this requirement stands out to me:

Encrypt transmission of cardholder data on open, public networks.

Email is very much NOT encrypted, and the internet (which emails use to send & receive) is an open public network! (As opposed to an intranet or internal network, which would be private).
In future you might want to use a virtual card or a disposable card, from a bank like Revolut, for paying merchants you don't trust. This gives you a different card number to your main physical card, whenever you want [another] one. Once you've used it you can freeze it (in the case of a virtual card) or it will automatically be deleted (in the case of a disposable card).
Thankfully the Hilton Hotel is a reputable company, but you could always get a rogue member of staff (in any company or country). Regarding the crime rates in Hong Kong:

In 2022, fraud cases rose 45 percent compared to the previous year. The first five months of 2023 saw an almost 60 percent increase in fraud cases.


Actually the Amazon example is not true. They ask for the CVV at the time of purchase when necessary (new card, changed address, use of VPN/proxy). This is because they have to pay a fee to do a verification without a transaction, and because it minimizes the time a "good" card is held in their system, which lowers overall risk.

@user71659 ICICI is India, not UK

It works the exact same in the US and I strongly suspect the UK as well. CVV is identically requested at checkout, so the part about Amazon is incorrect.

@user71659 In my 20 years on Amazon UK it has never asked me for CVV, even with lots of disposable cards https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21168/how-does-amazon-bill-me-without-the-cvc-cvv-cvv2 There was talk about changing it soon IIRC

It's incorrect. Your linked post is 12 years old. Here is a most recent post that shows you're wrong. The age is relevant because card networks started charging fees for test authorizations (misuse of authorization fee, zero dollar authorization fee). The screenshot is exactly how the CVV flow works in the US and apparently India. The only exception is services like 3-D Secure that add 2-factor via your bank.

https://www.bing.com/search?q=why+doesn%27t+amazon+ask+for+cvv  I’m “wrong” yet I’m the one using it not you. India appears to have different rules https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5124/why-do-some-online-stores-not-ask-for-the-3-digit-code-on-the-back-of-my-credit

Again, I've been asked multiple times in the US for CVV at checkout, the surefire way to trigger it is adding a new shipping address. Again, your assumption is plain wrong because you failed to consider, as the screenshot shows, them asking at checkout. This answer would have been good if you had accepted this fact and deleted all the wrong claims about Amazon, instead of choosing to argue against screenshot evidence.

@user71659 You are fast boring me. It is not “plain wrong”  You don’t live here, whether you live in the US or India is largely irrelevant - my answer clearly says the UK. The screenshot is from checkout, there is no additional verification, and I send to new shipping addresses all the time. You are disrespectful and becoming a disruption. I will not be responding to any more of your comments.
